# Xcode 8.1 targets contain source code developed with an older version of swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm using Xcode 8 and updating a project to swift 3. I am getting the following message when I open my workspace in Xcode 8.1.

```
The targets “Alamofire” and “DBAlertController” contain source code developed with an earlier version of Swift.
```

DerivedData mark$ pod --version `1.2.0.beta.1`

I have emptied `/Users/mark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Podfile

```
pod 'DBAlertController', :git => 'https://github.com/dbettermann/DBAlertController.git', :branch => 'swift3'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
```

Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!
```

I have also run pod update but did not fix it.

```
Marks-Mac:mark$ cd /Users/mark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
Marks-Mac:DerivedData mark$ rm -rf *
Marks-Mac:DerivedData mark$ cd
Marks-Mac:~ mark$ cd Documents/myProject
Marks-Mac:mark$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `DBAlertController` from `https://github.com/dbettermann/DBAlertController.git`, branch `swift3`
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (3.1.0)
Installing Alamofire (4.0.1)
Installing DBAlertController (0.3.0)
```

Comment: did you specify the platform like "platform :ios, '9.0'"

Comment: or try to run "pod update"

Comment: update your pods, remove pods files, reset everything mostly

Comment: I have already tried removing the entire Pods directory several times.

Answer (score 0):

Closed and opened Xcode and it seems to have fixed itself apart from a header file for AFNetworking not found..